# Python: script only running when imported in terminal. MAC

Tags: python, macos, eval, textwrangler

For some reason my script refuses to run directly from Text Wrangler but works fine when imported into terminal.

```
import math

def main():
    print("This program find the real solutions to a quadratic\n")
    a,b,c, = eval(input("Please enter the coefficients (a,b,c): "))
    discRoot = math.sqrt(b * b -4 * a * c)
    root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2 * a)
    print("\nThe solutions are:" , root1, root2)


main()
```

When I run that in textwrangler, I get the error message "TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object". Isn't the point of using eval() to imply that the following input is an integer and not a string? Why is this happening?

Comment: why are you using eval?

Comment: I'm just beginning to learn python so I am following a book's instruction.

Comment: you should install ipython for python 2.7 and 3.4. There are a lot of cool extensions you can use.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(input())` in Python 3. I think that in the terminal you are running it with Python 3, but TextWrangler uses Python 2 Therefore TextWrangle is doing `eval(eval(input()))` - which evaluates to `eval(5)`, which causes the error you see.

To fix this, you need to update TextWrangler, or use Python 2 in the terminal. If you want the second option, you should replace `eval(input())` with `input()`.

Side note - using `eval` like this is a bad idea (it's dangerous). You should probably do something like `a, b, c = map(int, input().split(","))` (in Python 3) instead.

Comment: Yes, I am using 3.4.1 in terminal. Should I add a Shebang line in my script to correct this or is there a way to make TextWrangler run with  Python 3.4?

Comment: I'd imagine there is a way to make TextWrangler work with Python 3.4 (most decent text editors should be able to) but I don't know what it is.

Comment: The map function worked great, thank you so much. Were you saying that eval is dangerous if my input is a tuple? It's OK if it's just a single value right?

Comment: No. As `eval` evaluates any code it gets, someone could enter something like `__import__("subprocess").Popen("delete all the files on the computer")`, and it would be executed. Beyond that, it is just bad style.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `eval`. The problem is with `input`, which tries to read from `sys.stdin`, the standard input stream.

If you want to get around it, you should pass the argument to `eval` as an argument instead of using `input`.